# how to change the home directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

help please do redirect. have the following kind of structure:

```
site.ru (catalog) 
     index.php (file) 
     . htaccess (file) 
     catalog.php (file) 
     landing (catalog) 
         index.php (file)
```

in the browser when loading address site.ru file opens site.ru / index.php

but I need to when loaded into a browser address site.ru opened file site.ru / catalog / index.php

wherein the browser address would be as follows: 
site.ru
ie without the phrase "catalog"

Comment: what are you using? you want to "simply change .htaccess" or create "routes" by your own?

Comment: Replace `DocumentRoot /path/to/site.ru/` with `DocumentRoot /path/to/site.ru/catalog/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `catalog.php` because you don't have a directory `catalog` and inside it `index.php`.

So to achieve this, in your `.htaccess` file, use the [`DirectoryIndex` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html):

```
DirectoryIndex catalog.php index.php index.html
```

If you want to open `landing/index.php` (in your code, you have `(catalog)` next to `landing`), then adjust the line like this:

```
DirectoryIndex landing/index.php index.php index.html index.htm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting this into your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index.php$  /catalog/index.php  [L]
```

If it works, search for mod_rewrite examples on google. You will find many.